# Automate data import from excel to SQL

Tags: excel, database, automation, powerbi

i am working on a power Bi project, i need a lot of excel files to be uploaded regularly ( every 15 min) load the data into SQL tables ( truncate the data before the insertion > upload new data) ? how can i do it ? and is it even possible ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow,  help us help you by asking a question in the right way. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It may help to show what you have tried, some example data, or screenshots and expected outcomes. Most likey you'll need 
SSIS or Azure Data Factory, you need to update your question about the file locations and sql type, on prem or cloud

Comment: thank you for your time, is there any article about the Azure data Factory because i have tried the SSIS solution but it is a static solution, i am currently working with microsfot sql server studio 2019.

Comment: Well, you can schedule a job to run in SQL Server, but I don't think it goes as frequent as every 15 minuets. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/schedule-a-job?view=sql-server-ver15

You can schedule a job to run using Task Scheduler, in Windows, and I think this will run as frequent as every 15 minutes.

https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10

The real question becomes ... is this a good idea or the right technology for the job? Answer: probably not.